# Crop strip background when combining long and short facet labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have plot where the facet labels are very long in one category, but much shorter in the second category.
However, the strip background fits the long labels, but expands too much on the shorter labels.

Let's say we have the following plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid("Here be a very very long label" + Species ~ ., switch = "y") +
  theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
    strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black") # Just for indication
  )
```

I'm specifically interested in reducing the margin around the second layer of strips, indicated in red below:

[image]

I know how I would be able to construct a facet function or edit the plot at the grid graphics/gtable level, I'm just asking around to see if anyone would know of a simpler solution. I'm not looking to wrap, rotate or resize the long labels; I want to shrink the margins around the short ones.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Why not insert line breaks `\n` in the longer label instead? E.g. `"Here be a \nvery very\n long label"`

Comment: Yeah I consider that string wrapping, which `stringr::str_wrap()` can do automatically is you give it a desired with. The reason this won't work for me is that in my real case I already wrapped the long labels, but the short labels are single letters. This leaves a lot of  empty space around the short labels.

Comment: I think it can be done at the fundamental level by tweaking the underlying code over at `ggplot2:::assemble_strips`, but it won't be trivial. See [GH discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3683): "There is still some special considerations to be done, as strips are sized to the largest strip for alignment and this has to be done after the creation of the titleGrob..." You'll probably have an easier time hacking the gtable.

Comment: That is a fair point, thanks for pointing me to the discussion; it was helpful to read!